# Can't connect to Windows Internal Database with SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to connect using the following connection string, and Windows Authentication (Trying both to log in using the Administrator account, and the account I used when setting up the SQL Server installation.)

`\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query`

Yet, I get a file not found error, and can't think why the file might not have been found... Any ideas?

Here's the error text: http://pastebin.com/gSBAWykU

Comment: Are you sure it's been installed on that system?  If so, are you running SSMS with administrator (elevated) privileges?  Not sure about with 2012 but previous versions you have to connect with the account you set it up with, so that's the account to stick with.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're running WID 2012?  If not, the connection string changed with 2012 and used to be \.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query.

If that doesn't help, check services and make sure it's running, and look for an error log.

2005 location:  C:\Windows\SYSMSI\SSEE\MSSQL.2005\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG

2012 location:  %WINDIR%\WID\Log\error.log

One of those might provide you with some insight.